# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package' on ubuntu

Tags: python

I have a python project which is structured like this:

```
package/
  __init__.py
  conf/
    my_conf.py
    __init__.py
  lib/
    tasks/
      somecode.py
      __init__.py
```

In `somecode.py` I am importing from conf like:

```
from package.conf.my_conf import somevar
```

When I try to execute the code in command line using:

```
python3 package/lib/tasks/somecode.py
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

This happens on Ubuntu 18 and is really weird because I run the exact same command on my Mac and have no issues. It is worth to mention that I have python 3.6 on Ubuntu and 3.7 on my Mac. Does that make a difference?

I have been reading posts on SO and the fact that relative imports are gone but I don't think that's the issue in my case because otherwise it wouldn't work on my Mac. However, I gave that a shot and updated my code to:

```
from ...conf.my_conf import somevar
```

And I am now getting a new error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I also have set my `PYTHONPATH` on Ubuntu to:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/:/home/myusername/package/
```

and that didn't help as well. This has become a hassle and I have not been able to find a good resource which would explain it all. So any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that I run `from package.conf.my_conf import somevar` within python3 itself without any issues.

Comment: Add root directory where package is located (`/home/myusername/`) to PYTHONPATH instead of that path. Python package is directory in filesystem.

Comment: @ipaleka still getting `No module named 'package'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the issue and I'm posting it here just in case it might help someone else. As mentioned in the question, I realized that I had no issue running the following code:

```
python
from package.conf.my_conf import somevar
```

So I figure there must be something different between my terminal and python command line. So I compared `PYTHONPATH` in both cases:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

in my terminal printed:

```
/home/myusername
```

And the following from python:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

printed:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

So I updated the `PYTHONPATH` in terminal using:

```
export PYTHONPATH=export PYTHONPATH=/home/myusername:/usr/lib/python36.zip:/usr/lib/python3.6:/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

And that fixed the issue. So in summary I took the following steps:

1. Made sure `__init__.py` exist in all sub directories
2. `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your import to

```
from .package.conf.my_conf import somevar
```

Notice the Dot(.) before "package". It tells python to look into current directory instead of going and searching into python libraries directory.

Comment: This causes: `attempted relative import with no known parent package`