# ModuleNotFoundError on different OS with same setup for local package

Tags: python, module, package, python-import, importerror

Essentially, the main issue is that a package is not being seen for importing on Ubuntu where it is for Git Bash on Windows.

Here is the relevant directory structure with the library folder being the problematic package/module.

```
project-dir/
    services/
        task.py
    library/
        __init__.py
        module.py
```

In the `task.py` file, I have imports that take the following syntax:

```
from library.module import function
```

In the `project-dir` folder, I run the following command: `python services/task.py`.

On Git Bash on Windows, this works perfectly. However, on Ubuntu, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` thrown. Below is the abstracted aforementioned error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "services/task.py", line 3, in <module>
    from library.module function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library'
```

Note: I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346352/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-package-on-ubuntu), which looks very similar to my question, but adding things to `PYTHONPATH` did not fix things. Here is the output for `PYTHONPATH` for me:

```
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3.6:/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Comment: What did you try adding to the `PYTHONPATH` on Ubuntu?

Comment: @forty_two All of the items mentioned at the end of the post are what I added.

Comment: @forty_two To clarify, each of the items that are separated by colons in the output of `echo "$PYTHONPATH"` are what I added.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarification. Did you try adding the project dir to the `PYTHONPATH`; something like `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/project-dir/`?

Comment: @forty_two That does result in it working, though I am confused as to why that would be required, considering that it isn't required on Git Bash.

Comment: Glad that got it to work! I'm not familiar with Git Bash and don't develop Python on Windows so I don't think I'll be able to help resolve why there is a difference. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one posted an answer, and @forty_two happened to give me insight into what I need to do, I will explain my implementation of his suggestion.

I created a file called `add_project_path.py` in the services directory. The scripts contents is as follows:

```
import sys
import os

# Adds the project path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
```

This gets the `add_project_path.py`'s path, gets the directory in which it resides, and gets that directory's parent directory, which is the project folder. Then, the project folder is added to the path, which solves the issue.

**Edit:**

Also, to explain further, I added `import add_project_path` at the top of my imports for `task.py`, which allowed the `add_project_path` module to import the project path before any of the other imports occur.